# Update ModalBottomSheet after api call in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet, flutter-dialog

I am new flutter , developing an application which call an api and fetching data from server which is showing on a bottom sheet. in this case Iam showing the bottom sheet meanwhile perfroming the api call. After the api call I want to update the content of the bottom sheet. I have used a data object to show the content in the bottom sheet. the setstate is not updating the already showed bottomsheet. How can I update the bottom sheet content after the api call.

My APi call

```
model.getSpotDetails(model.spotList[position], position).then((value) =>
      {
        if(value){

        }
      });
```

My Bottom sheet code

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      elevation: 5,
      backgroundColor: AppTheme.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(20),topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context,setState){
            return Container(
              height: 370,
              child: bottomContent(data),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

use future builder and then update your bottom sheet

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: Provide more explanation and example to the answer.